# How to dynamically change background color of a buttonBar wrt selected in Mathematica

Tags: button, background

I have a ButtonBar like this and on click I want to change the color of the pressed button dynamically.
Which is the properly way to do this in Mathematica ?
My code:

```
  color = {Blue,Red,Red},
  
  buttonBar = ButtonBar[{
      "First Button ":>{
        color = {Blue,Red,Red}
        Print["Clicked 1"],
      },
      
      "Second Button ":>{
        color = {Red,Blue,Red}
        Print["Clicked 2"],
      },
      
      "Third Button ":>{
        color = {Red,Red,Blue}
        Print["Clicked 3"],
      },
    }, 
    Background -> Dynamic[color],
    Appearance -> "Vertical",
    ImageSize -> {100,30}, 
    Background->Lighter[Gray, 0.80]
  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SetOptions[Framed, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {100, 30}];

color = {LightBlue, LightRed, LightRed};
x = "";
buttonBar = ButtonBar[{
   Framed["First Button",
     Background -> 
      Dynamic[color[[1]]]] :> (color = {LightBlue, LightRed, 
       LightRed}; x = "Clicked 1"),
   Framed["Second Button",
     Background -> 
      Dynamic[color[[2]]]] :> (color = {LightRed, LightBlue, 
       LightRed}; x = "Clicked 2"),
   Framed["Third Button",
     Background -> 
      Dynamic[color[[3]]]] :> (color = {LightRed, LightRed, 
       LightBlue}; x = "Clicked 3")},
  Appearance -> "Vertical",
  ImageSize -> {100, 30},
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.80]]
Dynamic[x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`ButtonBar` does not allow access to button indices and it does not allow individual styling of buttons.

You can easily create your own button bar with more flexible styling options. For example:

```
ClearAll[indexedButton]
SetAttributes[indexedButton, HoldRest]

indexedButton[label_, action_, defaultbackground_, pressedbackground_, index_: 1] :=
 Block[{bI}, 
  Button[label, (bI = index; action), 
   Appearance -> Dynamic[bI /. {index -> "Pressed", _ -> Automatic}], 
   Background -> Dynamic[bI /. {index -> (pressedbackground /. 
       Automatic -> Lighter[Lighter @ defaultbackground]), _ -> defaultbackground}]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
labels = {"First Button", "Second Button", "Third Button"};

actions = {Unevaluated @ Print["Clicked 1"], 
   Unevaluated @ Print["Clicked 2"], 
   Unevaluated @ Print["Clicked 3"]};


DynamicModule[{bI = 0}, 
 Column[MapIndexed[indexedButton @@ Join[##] &, 
   Thread[{labels, actions, Red, Green}]], Spacings -> 0]]
```

[image]

You can also organize a list of buttons in a `Grid` with desired options:

```
ClearAll[buttonGrid]

buttonGrid[list_, dims_: Automatic, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Grid[ArrayReshape[list, dims /. Automatic -> {Length @ list, 1}], opts,
   Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

***Examples:***

```
DynamicModule[{bI = 0}, 
 buttonGrid @ 
  MapIndexed[indexedButton @@ Join[##] &, 
   Thread[{labels, actions, Red, Green}]]]
```

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{bI = 0}, 
 buttonGrid[MapIndexed[indexedButton @@ Join[##] &, 
   Thread[{labels, actions, Red, Green}]], 
  Automatic, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> White, 
  Spacings -> {{2, {.5}, 2}, {2, {.5}, 2}}, 
  Background -> LightBlue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
is = 2 Rasterize["Second Button", "RasterSize"];

buttonbar := DynamicModule[{clickedbutton = ""}, 
  ButtonBar[Panel[#, FrameMargins -> 1, 
       Background -> Dynamic[clickedbutton /. {#2 -> #3, _ -> #4}], 
       Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ImageSize -> is] :> 
      Print[clickedbutton = #2] & @@@ 
  {{"First Button", "Clicked 1", Red, Orange}, 
   {"Second Button", "Clicked 2", Red, Orange}, 
   {"Third Button", "Clicked 3", Red, Orange}}, 
   Appearance -> "Vertical", 
   FrameMargins -> 5, 
   Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.80]]]


buttonbar
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [`SetterBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html) instead of `ButtonBar`:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
  SetterBar[Dynamic[x, (x = #; Print["Clicked " <> ToString[#]]) &],
    {1 -> "First Button", 2 -> "Second Button", 3 -> "Third Button"}, 
    Background -> Orange, Appearance -> {"FramedPalette", "Vertical"}]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Changing the background color for `"Pressed"` mode is a challenge.